# Unable to see Archives on Amazon

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

```
BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("...", "...");

    client = new AmazonGlacierClient(awsCreds);

    client.setEndpoint("https://glacier.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/");

    try {
        ArchiveTransferManager atm = new ArchiveTransferManager(client, awsCreds);

        UploadResult result = atm.upload(vaultName, "my archive2" + (new Date()), new File(archiveToUpload));
        System.out.println("Archive ID: " + result.getArchiveId());

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
```

I got the archive ID generated in response but not able to see file that I uploaded at  https://console.aws.amazon.com/glacier/home?region=us-east-1#/vaults

Answer (score 0):

I got the reason from the Amazon documentation. Its because Amazon updates the list once in a day and it takes some time to show up there.